# QueryInterface returns E_ACCESSDANIED general access denied error after successfull CoCreateInstanceEx

Tags: c++, com, dcom

I am making a simple client to connect to an OPC Server via DCOM on a virtual machine.
I tested the same code on a Windows 7 Machine and it worked properly, but after moving the coding to Windows 10 it stopped working (the virtual machine containing the DCOM server is the same).
The point is that I am able to instantiate a the COM object but I am not able to call any of its methods because I am receiving the E_ACCESSDENIED result.
These are the steps:

```
tagMULTI_QI res;
res.pIID = &__uuidof(IOPCServer);
res.pItf = NULL;

hr = CoCreateInstanceEx(
    clsid,
    NULL,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    &sin,
    1,
    &res);
```

This returns hr = S_OK and the res.hr has S_OK value as well.
But after that any call retrieves E_ACCESSDENIED result.
This is:

```
hr = server->GetStatus(&status);

IOPCItemProperties* ItemProperties;

hr = server->QueryInterface(
            __uuidof(IOPCItemProperties),
            (void**)&ItemProperties);
```

Any idea what can be causing the problem? Could be someting related to the Windows 10 OS?

Comment: What's `server`, and how, if at all, is it related to `CoCreateInstanceEx` call?

Comment: You say you want to use DCOM to connect to another machine - but you are passing `CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER` to `CoCreateInstanceEx`. That can't possibly instantiate a remote server.

Comment: @Igor many thanks for the support. CoCreateInstanceEx is working well, the result is S_OK whether I use CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER, but after getting the instance of the server any call returns E_ACCESSDENIED result. The Server is a OPC server running on  a Windows Xp machine and DCOM is configured properly. The point is the same code works using a Windows 7 machine, but not on a Windows 10 one.

Comment: If the machines talking to each other have different Windows versions you might have to change some registry settings as well:
For instance these settings:

"Network security: LAN Manager authentication level". 
The NTLM authentication level should be set to: “Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated”

"Network security: Minimum session security for NTLM SSP based (including secure RPC) clients.
Set to "Require 128-bit encryption"

"Network security: Minimum session security for NTLM SSP based (including secure RPC) servers.